# In init: Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange situation in Swift 3:

When I write the following code:

```
let color = UIColor.white

init() {
  super.init()

  let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10),
         NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color]
}
```

I get the error `Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional`.

I totally understand that.

**BUT:**

When I write it like this:

```
init() {
  super.init()

  let color = UIColor.white
  let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10),
         NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color]
}
```

, or like this:

```
static let color = UIColor.white

init() {
  super.init()

  let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10),
         NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: MyClass.color]
}
```

, or define the attributes variable in another function (not `init`), it works without the error.

It must be something special with the state of attributes during the init function, but does anyone have more insight in what exactly is the issue here?

ADDITION:

This also works:

```
let color = UIColor.white

init() {
  super.init()

  let color2 = color
  let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10),
         NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color2]
}
```

Comment: Class properties are initialized when your class is instantiated, so your `let color = UIColor.white` is only executed after `init()`. Statics are heap allocated so they are present before your class gets instantiated, local vars just follow the order of operations of your code.

Comment: But still the compiler could derive the dictionary type - when I define a color as instance variable `let color = UIColor.white`, then assign that variable in the init function to another variable `let color2 = color`, and then use color2 in the dictionary definition, it does not complain

Comment: So the compiler does some derivation of types in the init function